# if condition to check for yum or apt

Tags: command-line, bash

I try to achieve writing a Bash script for automated setup of a Linux box. Depending on installed OS, Ubuntu or CentOS, I want to run different stuff. But somehow that if condition does not seem to work (at least on CentOS).

```bsh
if [[ -n "command -v apt-get" ]]; then
  echo "apt-get is used here"

elif [[ -n "command -v yum" ]]; then
  echo "yum is used here"

else
  echo "I have no Idea what im doing here"
fi
```

On CentOS, `command -v apt-get` returns nothing in my shell, but the script still runs that part through.

I'm not sure what I miss here.

Answer (score 4):

You are not executing the `command` at all. You'd need to use [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to execute it (i.e. `$(...)` or the less-preferred backticks). What you do simply check the string, so the first `if` statement is always going to be true.

But to check for existence, you don't need to check output of `command` - just testing the return code is sufficient.

```
#!/bin/bash

if command -v apt-get >/dev/null; then
  echo "apt-get is used here"
elif command -v yum >/dev/null; then
  echo "yum is used here"
else
  echo "I have no Idea what im doing here"
fi
```